# how to make same format from dataframe in r

Tags: r

I have dataframe something like:

```
myData <-  User                        App
            17567123@hvr.ac.uk         Wa
            17567123                   Browsing
            17567123@students.ac.uk    Wa
            hvr.ac.uk\17567123         Browsing
            17567124@students.ac.uk    Youtube
            17567124                   Ig
            Jhon                       Wa
```

To something like this:

```
> myData

   User        App
1  17567123   Wa 
2  17567123   Browsing
3  17567123   Wa
4  17567123   Browsing
5  17567124   Youtube 
6  17567124   Ig     
7  Jhon       Wa
```

Question
I want to make same format for **User** column. Any idea on how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So you want keep numbers/digits from user column and allocate an unique id to each thereafter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Does this work:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
myData %>% mutate(NewUser =str_remove(User, '@?gmail[\\.\\/]com/?'))
# A tibble: 7 x 3
  User        App      NewUser
  <chr>       <chr>    <chr>  
1 A@gmail.com Wa       A      
2 A           Browsing A      
3 A@gmail.com Wa       A      
4 gmail/com/A Browsing A      
5 B@gmail.com Youtube  B      
6 B           Ig       B      
7 B           Wa       B
```

Answer (score 1):

We can extract the number from the `User` column and for each number assign a unique letter to it.

```
library(dplyr)

df %>%
  mutate(num = stringr::str_extract(User, '\\d+'), 
         User1 = LETTERS[match(num, unique(num))]) -> df
df
#                     User      App      num User1
#1      17567123@hvr.ac.uk       Wa 17567123     A
#2                17567123 Browsing 17567123     A
#3 17567123@students.ac.uk       Wa 17567123     A
#4      hvr/ac/uk/17567123 Browsing 17567123     A
#5 17567124@students.ac.uk  Youtube 17567124     B
#6                17567124       Ig 17567124     B
#7                17567124       Wa 17567124     B
```

Comment: What if in user column the value is id number. Example 17523891, 18927872 and else

Comment: You should update your example accordingly and show expected output for it.

Comment: @DioAgusNofrizal Ok...can you check if my updated answer helps?